# Minimum Rate of Return

Tags: finance, economics

**Question:** A businessman wishes to earn 7% on his capital after payment of taxes. If the income from an available investment will be taxed at an average of 42%, what minimum rate of return, before the payment of taxes, must the investment offer to be justified?

This is a question under "Simple Interest" from the book I am using. The formulas I know in that topic is:

Simple Interest = (Principal Cost)(rate of interest)(number of periods)

Simple Interest = Future amount - Principal amount. Where in F = P (1 + in)

Rate of Return = [(Current value - Original Value) / (Original Value)] x 100

But I can't relate any of those formula for the problem above. The book shows no solution, just the correct answer: **12.07&** Tried to search online for the solutions but no luck.

Just a clue would suffice on how to answer the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Don't blindly rely on formulas!  If your pre-tax return is $r$ then your post-tax return is $.58\times r$ (since you pay $.42\times r$ in tax).   Thus you want to solve $.58\times r= 7$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. While we get the correct answer from that equation. I don't really get why could just simply multiply or divide those percentages. At least I have encountered this kind of problem and I'll just remember how you answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find it helps to convert the problem into words and use a convenient $100 starting sum such that the math becomes obvious. Instead of blindly guessing which standard formula to use, it helps in determining a correct formula and intuitively understanding the solution. With that.....

$\$100$ times the rate of return times $0.58$ (the amount after taxes) equals $\$7$

Here you can see why simply multiplying the two given percentages doesn't work. The quantity of interest is the amount remaining after taking out 42% in tax.

Now we can substitute the rate of return for $r$ and solve the equation.

$100r \cdot 0.58 = 7$

$100r = 12.07$

$r = .1207$ or $12.07\%$

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. I need to practice this kind of mentality when answering certain word problems.